# Exception executing a stored procedure with CASE switching from C# (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case-when

I have a NVARCHAR(max) column in a table and a stored procedure that would update this column as well as any other column in the table using CASE switching:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateTable
   @columnName sysname,
   @value nvarchar(max)
AS 
   UPDATE [dbo].[TestTable]
   SET 
      BigNvarcharValue = CASE @columnName WHEN 'BigNvarcharValue' THEN @value ELSE BigNvarcharValue END,  
      TableName = CASE @columnName WHEN 'TableName' THEN @value ELSE TableName END
```

All is good if I execute this procedure from SQL Management Studio with

```
EXEC [dbo].[updateTable]
     @columnName = 'BigNvarcharValue',
     @value = N'SOME BIG 80Kb value'
```

I can also update TableName from C# code using the same stored procedure, but when it comes to updating this BigNvarcharValue from C#, it fails with SQLException that "String or binary data would be truncated". Now, I figured it has something to do with CASE in this stored procedure, because when I break it to a simpler stored procedure, everything works fine:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateTable   
     @columnName sysname,   
     @value nvarchar(max)
AS       
   UPDATE [dbo].[TestTable]   
   SET BigNvarcharValue=@value
```

I read a bunch of forum posts that describe this problem of trying to insert a bigger value into NVARCHAR column that would cause this exception, but it doesnt seem to apply.

I'm fairly new to T-SQL, so are there any limitations of CASE that I dont know of?

P.S. BigNvarcharValue is NVARCHAR(MAX) and TableName is NVARCHAR(50)

Comment: What are the SQL types of `BigNvarcharValue` and `TableName`? Also, why are you doing updates in this highly unusual way?

Comment: It sounds like its the C# code that's the problem

Comment: What's the size property set to on the SqlParameter

Comment: @Conrad - I tried setting it to everything - 4000, 8000, Int32.MaxValue, same problem... The thing that is driving me nuts is that the unit test passes if i execute all unit tests in bulk (with same exact setup!) and throws if i execute it by itself... Can lose all my hair like this...

Comment: @Andrew - BigNvarcharValue is NVARCHAR(MAX) and TableName is NVARCHAR(50). How else would you have just 1 stored procedure for updating all columns in a table without using dynamic-sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the data types of the columns you're dealing with?  Because I've reproduced the error by attempting to insert a value that is allowed by NVARCHAR(max) into a column that is VARCHAR(50).

To reiterate - NVARCHAR(max) is allowing you to specify a value that is longer than the stated data type, which is why you get the error about truncation.

Comment: BigNvarcharValue is NVARCHAR(MAX) and TableName is NVARCHAR(50).

Comment: @kateroh: Then the error can (and does) occur when you're updating the `tablename` value.

Comment: No, it does occur only when I update the other NVARCHAR(MAX) value. I have unit tests for both and both are obviously going through the same stored proc. The name gets successfully updated as does any other column that is not NVARCHAR(MAX) and that one doesnt. That's actually why it is so weird :(

Comment: @kateroh: I don't see how that can be, unless you got either the data types backwards, or the CASE statements are opposite.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - the worst is that the unit test passes if execute it in bulk with other tests (that also do updates through the same stored procedure!)... Urghhh

Comment: @kateroh, have you tried to remove the tablename case statement just in case there is something odd going on?

Answer (score 1):

The error says it by itself, "String or binary data would be truncated". This means that you seem to insert a larger value than what the `nvarchar(max)` can handle.

SSMS 2008 has some debugging features allowing to set breakpoints, etc.

I think you might wish to take an eye out to the `System.String` maximum capacity either. This is only a matter of length, somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

With your exact same stored procedure and the table you described I ran the following code

```
class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("updateTable",cnn);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@columnName",
                   System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128));

            cmd.Parameters["@columnName"].Value = "BigNvarcharValue";

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value",  
                     System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1));
            cmd.Parameters["@value"].Value = new string('T', 80000);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();



        }

    }
}
```

It worked fine. I would inspect the command text and the parameter collection (name and value) and verify every is as you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the responses. I ended up separating update of the big column to an individual procedure, which solved the problem. Im sure the culprit was with the CASE statement.